# loadin components through xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript

How to load flex components through xml?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to compile the component with mxmlc before loading it. Then you can load the component using the SWFLoader control. The SWFLoader control can load any swf generated by compiling Flex projects. (In AS3 at least).